# Visual Studio on M1 MacBook using Parallels

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, visual-studio, .net-framework, parallels

My Intel MacBook broke. I was using BootCamp to run Windows and create Windows Forms Applications (so with .Net Framework) using Microsoft Visual Studio.

I wanted to buy the new M1 MacBook Air but I am not sure I will be able to run Visual Studio and create Windows Forms Applications. I know Parallels can be used to install Windows Arm but I'm worried Windows ARM does not support .Net Framework.

This is kind of urgent..

Comment: Windows on ARM definitely supports .NET Core. Why don’t you just run [Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/mac-release-notes-preview) for MacOS? While I linked to a preview version the current stable version has already been released for more than a year now. Visual Studio supporting Windows on ARM is a different story, something, that should be easily researched.

Comment: @Ramhound MacOS version of Visual Studio does not support creation of Windows Forms Applications that is what I am trying to do. I researched on the internet but couldn't find clear info on whether it is actually possible to use .NET Framework on Windows on ARM..

Comment: .NET Core (the current version of .NET Framework) does indeed support ARM.  The question I cannot answer is if Visual Studio supporters being installed on Windows on ARM.  *I am going to guess it does not.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I bought the MacBook with M1 Processor. I am using Parallels to run a Windows 11 Virtual Machine.

Running Visual Studio on Windows 11 on Arm works fine. I can also create Windows Forms Applications. It's just a bit slower.